# Directory API - Why "get all groups for a member" doesn't return groups including all users?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-provisioning-api

I'm migrating from the old Google Provisioning API to the new Google Directory API. Previously when I retrieved all groups for a member, the result included groups where members is **All members of x.com**. The new directory API doesn't include these groups.